# Set a SP return value to a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a sproc that returns a single line and column with a text, I need to set this text to a variable, something like:

```
declare @bla varchar(100)
select @bla = sp_Name 9999, 99989999, 'A', 'S', null
```

but of course, this code doesn't work...

thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are unable to change the stored procedure, another solution would be to define a temporary table, and insert the results into that

```
DECLARE @Output VARCHAR(100)

CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
(
    OutputValue VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #tmpTable (OutputValue)
EXEC dbo.sp_name 9999, 99989999, 'A', 'S', null

SELECT
    @Output = OutputValue
FROM 
    #tmpTable

DROP TABLE #tmpTable
```

Comment: Would be very handy (if you had permissions) to set this up as your own stored proc with more value. Chances are you're going to want to call this multiple times.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me in T-SQL SQL2005.  My sp returns an int. I created the temp table, get no syntax errors and it runs, but then the int in the temp table has no value.  The solution provided by DiGi [ on this page ] did work for me. thx

Comment: It'd be better to use a Table Variable instead of a Temporal Table, to avoid performance issues, locks and it would not require special permissions.

Answer (score 19):

If the stored procedure is returning a single value you could define one of the parameters on the stored procedure to be an OUTPUT variable, and then the stored procedure would set the value of the parameter

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Name
    @In INT,
    @Out VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @Out = 'Test'
END
GO
```

And then, you get the output value as follows

```
DECLARE @OUT VARCHAR(100)
EXEC sp_name 1, @Out OUTPUT
PRINT @Out
```

Answer (score 15):

```
DECLARE
  @out INT

EXEC @out = sp_name 'param', 2, ...
```

More info in T-SQL "EXECUTE" [help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) (Help is from MSSQL 2008 but this works in 2000 too)

Comment: This only works for procedures that have OUT parameters. Not when the procedure returns a scalar value (which is the case for the original question.)

Comment: Works w/o out in 2012 at least, not tested for 2008