# How to store result of stored procedure in a variable using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on a SQL query where I have to store result of a stored procedure into a string type variable. There is a stored procedure named `SP_CheckAgentProperty` which is returning a string type of value either 'y' or 'N' or 'NP'.

I am passing an integer value to the stored procedure. I want to store this output in any string variable. For this I am using this SQL query:

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[SP_CheckAgentProperty] --12
(
    @ID bigint =null
)      
As
BEGIN
------Calculating total Ads Post allowed of any specific package of any user-----
DECLARE @Ad int=(SELECT tblPackage.Ads FROM tblPayment_Details INNER JOIN tblPayments ON tblPayments.ID = 
            tblPayment_Details.Payment_ID INNER JOIN tblPackage ON tblPayments.Package_ID = tblPackage.ID
            WHERE (tblPayment_Details.Payment_ID =(SELECT MAX(ID) AS d  FROM tblPayments AS tblPayments_1 WHERE (User_ID = @ID))))
            print @Ad
------Calculating the date when the user makes the last payment------
DECLARE @St DATE=(SELECT tblPayment_Details.Date FROM tblPayment_Details INNER JOIN tblPayments ON 
            tblPayments.ID = tblPayment_Details.Payment_ID INNER JOIN tblPackage ON tblPayments.Package_ID = tblPackage.ID
            WHERE (tblPayment_Details.Payment_ID =(SELECT MAX(ID) AS d  FROM tblPayments AS tblPayments_1 WHERE (User_ID = @ID))))
            print @St
------Calculating the validity of specific package taken by any user-----
DECLARE @LT int=(SELECT tblPackage.Validity FROM tblPayment_Details INNER JOIN tblPayments ON tblPayments.ID = 
            tblPayment_Details.Payment_ID INNER JOIN tblPackage ON tblPayments.Package_ID = tblPackage.ID
            WHERE (tblPayment_Details.Payment_ID =(SELECT MAX(ID) AS d  FROM tblPayments AS tblPayments_1 WHERE (User_ID = @ID))))
            print @LT
print dateadd(DAY,@LT,@St)
-------Calculating the Remaining days of package taken by the user
DECLARE @NoOfDays int=(select DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),dateadd(DAY,@LT,@St)))
print @NoOfDays 
-------Calculating if the user makes does not any payment in history------
DECLARE @SS int=(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), @St), 0))
IF(@SS='0')
BEGIN
    select 'NP' as Message
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    if(@NoOfDays<=0)
    BEGIN
        --select 'This User Does Not Make a Payment.' as Message
        select 'MP' as Message
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TOT int=(select count(*) from tblProperty where tblProperty.Date between @St and dateadd(DAY,@LT,@St)) 
        --group by tblProperty.ID
        --select count(*) from tblProperty where tblProperty.Date between '2015-07-04' and dateadd(DAY,20,'2015-07-04')
        IF(@TOT<@Ad)
        BEGIN
            select 'y' as Message
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            select 'N' as Message
        END
    END
END
END
```

And I am using the above stored procedure like this:

```
declare @ss varchar(10)

exec @ss = SP_CheckAgentProperty 10

if(@ss='NP')
BEGIN
    print 'Not Payment'
END
else
BEGIN
  print 'Payment'
END
```

The above query is returning the appropriate result but when I am using its output in if condition then it is not working.

Comment: Please post the code of `SP_CheckAgentProperty`.

Comment: Check this answer : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965269/how-to-return-the-output-of-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211758/set-a-sp-return-value-to-a-variable-in-sql-server

Comment: Check this answer : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965269/how-to-return-the-output-of-stored-procedure-into-a-variable-in-sql-server


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211758/set-a-sp-return-value-to-a-variable-in-sql-server

Comment: Stored procedure can return only `int`, so show us the code of your stored procedure.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I have written my stored procedure above.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the procedure is "returning" the value by selecting it, you'll have to use insert into with something like this:

```
declare @ss table (ss varchar(10))

insert into @ss exec SP_CheckAgentProperty 10

if(exists (select 1 from @ss where ss='NP') ...
```

or if it has an output parameter, then the call should be:

```
declare @ss varchar(10)

exec SP_CheckAgentProperty 10, @ss output

if(@ss='NP')
```

Comment: ¿Is it possible to select an specific resultset from a procedure that returns several resultsets ?

Comment: I found that it's only possible adding a CLR procedure to the database that adds that functionality.   https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-save-results-of-a-procedure-with-more-than-one-result-set