# Result of a stored procedure save in another stored procedure as a parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to save the result of one stored procedure into another stored procedure, 
but it always saves 0.

My procedure is:

```
Create Proc AddToBill
    @BillID INT,
    @CustomerID INT,
as
begin
    exec @BillID = BillID_Counter;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[FullBillDetails] ([BillID], [CustomerID])
    VALUES (@BillID, @CustomerID INT)
end
```

This procedure `BillID_Counter` only returns a single integer.

[Their is similar question but it has to many parameter and difficult to understand my Question is related to single parameter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423660/how-to-store-result-of-stored-procedure-in-a-variable-using-sql-server)

Comment: This is your other stored procedure: `BillID_Counter`? Output parameters should do the work for you, but I do not understand why you get @BbillID as param, but then you set it in the body of your stored procedure.

Comment: yes which return only single integer

Comment: This is the standard behavior for a stored procedure unless you specify additional outputs.

Comment: i want to save the result of BillID_Counter in @BillID

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store result of stored procedure in a variable using SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423660/how-to-store-result-of-stored-procedure-in-a-variable-using-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need to see the code of the `BillID_Counter` sp, but I can bet that the sp is performing a `SELECT`, which you are trying to get to that variable. What is actually happening though, is that you are giving `@BillID` the return code of the sp (0 means "succesful execution).

You could try this instead:

```
CREATE PROC AddToBill @BillID INT, @CustomerID INT,
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #BillID(BillID INT);

INSERT INTO #BillID
EXEC BillID_Counter;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FullBillDetails]([BillID],[CustomerID])
SELECT BillID, @CustomerID
FROM #BillID;

END
```